# How to resolve 405 Error on deployment with formspree?

Tags: reactjs, forms, server

I have this react component that submits a form to a given **formspree's** endpoint. When testing locally everything works fine: after submission it redirects to a new page with a thank you message.

But when depolyed to GitHub pages or Vercel, after clicking submit, the redirection displays a **405** error, "**Method not allowed.**"

How do I resolve this?

And if possible, is there a way to stop the redirection after submission and still submit the form correctly?

```
function Form(){
  return(
    <form action="https://formspree.io/someOtherString" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="name"></input>
      <input type="email" name="email"></input>
      <input type="text" name="message"></input>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research I found the solution. First of all I want to shed some light on **formspree**: it is a service that provides a free backend API for **forms**, saving you the time and resources of setting up and hosting it yourself.

The simple fix was to use a JS library like **axios** to abstract away all the complexities with HTTP requests.
Below is the updated code snippet:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Form(){
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    message: "",
 });

 const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
 };

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post("https://formbold.com/someOtherString",formData);
      console.log(response.data);
      alert("Thanks, we will get in touch.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error submitting form:", error);
      alert("An error occurred while submitting the form.");
    }
  };


return(
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <input type="name" name="name" value={formData.name} onChange={handleChange} />
  <input type="email" name="email" value={formData.email} onChange={handleChange} />
  <input type="message" name="message" value={formData.message} onChange={handleChange} />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>;
)}
```

The response received will be logged to the console, just in case any error occurs.

Comment: What do the advertising bring to your answer? How is it necessary?

Comment: I am not affiliated with formspree in any way. I just found them to be very helpful and wished other developers would know about them.